# Multiple ranges on the one sliderInput

Tags: r, slider, shiny

I know how to create [a `sliderInput` of a value and a `sliderInput` of a range](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/slider-bar-and-slider-range.html).

```
# ui
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,

      # Copy the line below to make a slider bar 
      sliderInput("slider1", label = h3("Slider"), min = 0, 
        max = 100, value = 50)
    ),
    column(4,

      # Copy the line below to make a slider range 
      sliderInput("slider2", label = h3("Slider Range"), min = 0, 
        max = 100, value = c(40, 60))
    )
  ),

  hr(),

  fluidRow(
    column(4, verbatimTextOutput("value")),
    column(4, verbatimTextOutput("range"))
  )

))
```

However, I'd like a `sliderInput` with multiple ranges on the one slider. That is the ability to independently select three or more values on the one slider. My initial thought of setting `value = c(40, 60, 80)`  didn't work: the `80` was ignored. I appreciate that this feature might not be implemented.

Comment: what do you mean by "a sliderInput with multiple range" ?? at maximum if you have a bar, you can have two cursor indicating a maximal and minimal value. Ro you mena you want a slider from 0 to 100, two cursor at 5 and 20 defining a range from 5 to 20 and two others cursors at 50 and 75 defining the range 50-75?

Comment: did you think about it?

Comment: Multiple values on the one slider, essentially. Ideally they should be presented as (contiguous) ranges but just as ticks on a slider would be adequate.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment shiny sliderInput is implementing in shiny the jQuery Ion.RangeSlider (http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/en.html) as you can see from sliderInput function definition (https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/master/R/input-slider.R).

By construction Ion.RangeSlider has maximum two handles (by default range selection).

It has been requested to implement arbitrary number of handles to whom is responsible of the development of this plugin (IonDen). unfortunately he rejected the request.

The only way out seem to build your own htmlwidget based on other jquery sliders.